# BadMapError - Elixir/Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to make a custom validation, so I've made a function that runs in a changeset but I'm getting an error that doesn't seem to make much sense to me at the moment.

Here is my model:

```
@required_fields ~w(commissioner user_id league_id)a

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
      |> cast(params, @required_fields)
      |> validate_required(@required_fields)
      |> duplicate_check
  end

  def duplicate_check(_struct) do
    IEx.pry
  end
```

But when I run this code I get this error:

#### ERROR:

```
expected a map, got: :ok

BadMapError at GET /leagues/new
```

Comment: Try returning `_struct` from `duplicate_check`. `IEx.pry` returns `:ok` so it's probably that.

Comment: Perfect. Yea, that makes sense I need to keep passing the struct through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`duplicate_check` returns the return value of `IEx.pry` which is `:ok` which means `changeset` now returns `:ok` which causes that error to be thrown. You need to return the struct from `duplicate_check`:

```
def duplicate_check(struct) do
  IEx.pry
  struct
end
```

Also, you might want to call the variable `changeset` because after `cast` you'll have a Changeset, not a struct of the current module.